Getting featured image from WP_Query
I know this has been asked a few times, but so far I haven't been able to see my error. I have an AJAX call that hits a function from my functions.php file, but when I inspect the returned data there's no featured image url in the posts array. I figured I'd have to create a part of the array for the image so I looped over the query but I just get the last image each time. I figured that the featured image url would be a part of the posts array. What am I doing wrong here?

function load_more_blogs() {
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $_POST['page']
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
        $results = array(
            'posts' => $query->posts,
            'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID , 'post-thumbnail' ),
            'test' => $post->ID
        );
    // }
    

    wp_send_json_success($results);
    
    exit();
}



data: 
  image: "<img width=\"400\" height=\"400\" src=\"http://localhost:8888/wp- 
  content/uploads/2024/10/wp_dummy_content_generator_63.jpg\" class=\"attachment-post- 
  thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image\" alt=\"\" decoding=\"async\" 
  loading=\"lazy\" srcset=\"http://localhost:8888/wp- 
  content/uploads/2024/10/wp_dummy_content_generator_63.jpg 400w, 
  http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/wp_dummy_content_generator_63- 
  300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost:8888/wp- 
  content/uploads/2024/10/wp_dummy_content_generator_63-150x150.jpg 150w\" sizes=\"(max- 
  width: 400px) 100vw, 400px\" />"
  posts: (2) [{…}, {…}]
  test: 63
  [[Prototype]]: Object
  success: true


Suggest to reformat the data like such (untested):
function load_more_blogs() {
    ...

    $results = array();

    foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
        $results[] = array(
            'post'  => $post,
            'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' ),
        );
    }

    wp_send_json_success( $results );
    exit();
}

This will give you an array of arrays, with the inner array have two entries: post and image. They can be accessed like such:
print_r( $results[0]['post'] );
print_r( $results[0]['image'] );


Thank you so much. PHP isn't my usual language so you really helped me out here!
